# Conjugation in $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

What are the conjugates to $(12)$ in the symmetric group $S_3$?

I know that in the symmetric group the elements are as follows:
The identity, $(12)$, $(13)$, $(23)$, $(123)$, and $(132)$.

I want to find the conjugates of each of these with $(12)$. So I know you have to use the fact that if $h=(12)$ then $ghg^{-1}$ will get me my conjugate. However I'm confused as to how this happens.

How does $(132)(12)(132)^{-1}=(13)$?
Because surely, $(132)^{-1}$ is $(231)=(123)$
Then $(132)(12)(123)$ is what I need to compute.

This is my mind goes as follows:
Starting from RHS- 1 goes to 2 which goes to 1, so $(1)$
Then 2 goes to 3 which goes to 2 so $(132)(12)(123)=(1)(23)=(23)$?

I'm extremely confused and I just don't know how to work out these types of problems because I keep getting into trouble. 
Please someone help!

I can't also work out the conjugates of $(123)$.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the RHS, you have to go **entirely** to the left hand side. So for (132)(12)(123): 1 goes to 2, then 2 goes to 1, then 1 goes to 3, so $1\rightarrow 3$. Next 3 goes to 1, 1 goes to 2 and 2 goes to 1, so we have (13). You can now check that indeed: 2 goes to 3, 3 stays at 3, 3 goes back to 2. Conclusion: (132)(12)(123)=(13).

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!

Comment: I don't understand still :( I'm sorry!

What if I'm doing the conjugation of (123) on the elements of S3?
How do I compute (12)(123)(12)?

Comment: You just always do the same, going from right to left. E.g. in this case 1 will go to 3 since you have $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 3$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fact that two permutations are conjugated if and only if they have the same cycle structure (found in many standard textbooks). See e.g. **https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_Permutations_have_Same_Cycle_Type**

In particular the conjugates of $(12)$ in $S_3$ are $(13)$ and $(23)$. Moreover $(123)$ is conjugated to $(132)$ in $S_3$ (note that they are **not** conjugated in $A_3$).

Comment: so how would I go about finding the conjugacy classes in A4 because some of the elements which they conjugate to aren't in the subgroup A4?

Comment: If you have a conjugacy class in $S_n$ consisting entirely of even permutations (i.e. all elements of the class lie in $A_n$) then there are two possibilites. Either this class remains one in $A_n$ or it splits into two conjugacy classes. In this particular example $|A_3| = \frac{3!}{2} = 3$, i.e. $A_3$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order 3, in particular it is abelian (so all conjugacy classes are singletons).